# Mysql Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, adsl

I want to be able to replicate a local mysql db to an online mysql db over adsl.

My adsl ip is dynamic, so I dont have static ip.

I use a custom application to fill the local db, the app uses quite a lot of cpu and the on webserver that hosts the online db is suffering when I run the app online.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks lin advance for any help.

Regards

Potman100

Comment: DNS names are allowed AFAIK, so use dyndns or similar?

Answer (score 1):

You must use [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) and data transport protocol doesn't metter.

You can use a [Dynamic DNS service](http://www.dyndns.com/) for get constant DNS address with A or AAAA record (A is for IPv4, AAAA is for IPv6) pointed always to your dynamic adsl IP address.

Comment: Hi, the problem I have is when setting up the config, the slave requires an ip for the master, as I have a dynamic ip on my adsl connection I cant supply an ip. I need to be able to push any changes from the master (Local) db, to the online db, rather than the slave requesting updates from the master.

Comment: @potman100: You can use dynamic dns service like a dyndns.org to get const dns with A record poited always to your dynamic adsl.

Comment: He can't, as the config file requires an IP, not a DNS.